# Chrome fires mousemove even when mouse isn't moving?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

https://jsfiddle.net/uxhazvyb/

```
<!doctype html>
<p id="hello">Hello</p>
<script>
    document.getElementById('hello').addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        console.log('mousemove');
    }, false);
</script>
```

Open the console, hover your mouse over "hello", then just let your mouse sit. The mousemove event keeps triggering even when the mouse isn't moving. Is this a new bug?

EDIT: I observe this issue on the latest Windows stable, 46.0.2490.80 m, but I don't see it on the latest Ubuntu stable 46.0.2490.80.

Comment: I'm using chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 ubuntu. I dont see this error.

Comment: Confirming; no event with steady mouse. Have you tried to pick it up off the table? Some sensors are a bit janky on certain surfaces…

Comment: I had this problem a few years ago. My 'solution' was to save and check `e.x` and `e.y` to see if the mouse really had moved.

Comment: *sings* "And in that mouse....there was a bug....the prettiest bug....that you ever did see....the bug in the mouse, and the mouse on the desk, and event listeners fire all around, all around, event listeners fire all around!"

Comment: @rajuGT Confirmed issue happens on Windows but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rudie Yes, that's what I'm doing for now, comparing against previous xy values to detect superfluous mousemove triggers.

Comment: happens for me on windows 7

Comment: I can reproduce this with Chrome 54.0.2840.87m but not Firefox 50.1.0 on Windows 7.